# Add listbox to session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, listbox

Hi I have a listbox in my asp page.How to add listbox items to session to persists between page navigations

Can any one help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
    ListBox mylist = new ListBox();
    mylist.Items.Add(new ListItem("Tahir", "Tahir"));
    Session["ITEM"] = mylist;
    foreach (ListItem Item in ((ListBox)(Session["ITEM"])).Items)
    {          
        mylist.Items.Add(new ListItem(Item.Text, Item.Value));
    }
```

however you might want to put some check that whether session actually contains a listbox or not because the first time you load your page there will be no listbox in session and you have to store it as you load the page and then use it as you like.

Answer (score 3):

By default you can store any type of object in Session because it's stored in memory. So you could use it to store the [ListItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.listitemcollection.aspx) of the ListBox.

```
Session["MyListBoxItems"] = ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().ToArray();
```

and afterwards you can use [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.addrange.aspx) to restore them:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange((ListItem[])Session[ "MyListBoxItems" ]);
```

**Edit**: If you are using an older framework version use [CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.copyto.aspx):

```
ListItem[] myListItemArray = new ListItem[ ListBox1.Items.Count ];
ListBox1.Items.CopyTo(myListItemArray, 0);
Session[ "MyListBoxItems" ] = myListItemArray;
```

Comment: thaks hey i could not find cast<> property in my listbox items property. iam using vs2005

Comment: @Jaya: You're welcome. In general it's better to store only the DataSource of a databound control than the control itself in Session since you're also restoring things like ViewState etc. Apart from that you're only interested in the data not in the control.

Comment: Hello Tim, I know that saving the data collection is better approach than saving whole object but judging by the complexity of question I presented the simpler looking approach.